# Why isn't the declaration of OCaml's record type a synonym?

Tags: constructor, ocaml, record, type-synonyms

https://cs3110.github.io/textbook/chapters/data/type_synonym.html

As we can see above,

```
type a = int * int * int
```

`type a` is a synonym for `int * int * int`.

So, if we declare `int * int * int` by multiple names, they are all same type.

```
type a = int * int * int
type b = int * int * int
type c = int * int * int
```

`a` and `b` and `c` are the same types.

They do not have a data constructor. Indeed, need not, and should not because they are just a synonym.

However, when we look at records, it's quite different.

```
type a = { name : string }
type b = { name : string }
type c = { name : string }
```

`a` and `b` and `c` are different types.
We can prove it by the code below.

```
({ name = "something" } : a) = ({ name = "something" } : b) ;;

// This expression has type b but an expression was expected of type a
```

It acts like "newtype" in Haskell, without a use of data constructor.

I heard that in OCaml, records are a primitive notion and they have their own identity.
(You can see it from the url below.)

[No type constructor for record types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660666/no-type-constructor-for-record-types)

If then, why tuples and records act differently??

It makes me confuse.

I learned that the problem of duplicating the format of records can be solved by using a module.
So this kind of confusion is not a big deal.

But I want to know why there is an inconsistency between tuples and records.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason is type inference. When you write a function

```
let f x = x.a
```

then the type system would not be able to tell the type of `f` if it could be any record type with a field `a`.

There are ways around the ambiguity, namely *row polymorphism*, which is what OCaml uses for the inference of object types:

```
let f o = o#a  (* infers type f : < a : 'a; .. > -> 'a *)
```

Here, `<a : t; ..>` means any object type with a field `a` of type `t`. However, the drawback is that this flexibility requires a more heavyweight and costly runtime representation for objects.

That said, Standard ML, which is OCaml's sister language, does indeed make records and tuples the same thing (literally, `a * b * c` is just a shorthand for `{1 : a, 2 : b, 3 : c}` in SML), but then requires the programmer to insert type annotations to resolve possible ambiguities, like in the example above.